# JavaScript Extract Only value from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this array

```
data:[
{key: "1", value: "a"},
{key: "2", value: "b"},
{key: "3", value: "c"}]
```

i want to convert this array like this :

```
data:{"1","a","2","b","3","c"}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the [JS array reduce method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)?

Comment: the second example isn't a valid structure? if all you want is to flatten key/values into an array:  `data.flatMap(({key, value})=>[key,value])` or .map().flat()

Comment: what kind of object is Data.

Comment: Not even valid Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converts key value to key/value of a single object map.  Guessing this is what you actually want.

```js
data = [
{key: "1", value: "a"},
{key: "2", value: "b"},
{key: "3", value: "c"}]
data=Object.fromEntries(data.map(({key, value})=>[key,value]))
console.log(data)
console.log(data["2"])
```

or if you only want values in an array:

```js
data = [
{key: "1", value: "a"},
{key: "2", value: "b"},
{key: "3", value: "c"}]
data=data.map(({value})=>value)
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Thaannks :D it's work fine

Answer (score 0):

Use the `flatMap` and `Object.values` to get desired output. 
PS: your expected output not valid object. Assuming you wanted in array form.

```js
data = [
{key: "1", value: "a"},
{key: "2", value: "b"},
{key: "3", value: "c"}]

const output = data.flatMap(Object.values);

console.log(output)
```